# How do I define custom datatype in xsd?

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to check if a field in my XML is of type `positive double/decimal`. There is a `type="xs:positiveInteger"` datatype in XSD but no positive double or decimal. Is there a way to achieve this either by defining custom datatype or some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<xs:element name="data">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:float">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

i think this should do it. There may be a shorter way i'm still learning xsd.

Comment: I would rather use base as decimal rather than float in this case.

Comment: I'd say you've learned that bit of XSD then :). Either an xs:float or an xs:decimal would work given the original question.

Comment: At least according to http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_numeric.asp, there's no `float` type

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by defining decimal datatype with restriction as following.

```
<xs:simpleType name="positiveDecimal">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
    <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```